# How to implement Single Sign On (SSO) using oAuth2 with Spring Security?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-boot, oauth-2.0

I need to by pass the loging process of child application and pass on the session id and access token from master application.

User accesses Application 1:

1. Application 1 needs the user to sign on, so its sends a token to the auth server through the back channel.
2. Application 1 then redirects the user to the log in page on the auth server with the token as a parameter on the request.
3. User logs in to auth server. Auth server sets a cookie, flags the token as authenticated and associates the user details with it. Auth server then redirects user back to application 1.

4.Application 1 gets request from user and calls auth server over back channel to check if the token is OK. Auth server response with user details.

5.Application 1 now knows that the user is authorised and has some basic user details.

Now this is where the SSO bit comes in.

User accesses application 2.

1. Application 2 needs the user to sign on, so its sends a token to the auth server through the back channel.

2.Application 2 then redirects the user to the log in page on the auth server with the token as a parameter on the request.

3.Auth server sees that there is a valid log in cookie, so it can tell that the user is already authenticated, and knows who they are. Auth server flags the token as authenticated and associates the user details with it. Auth server then redirects user back to application 2.

4.Application 2 gets request from user and calls auth server over back channel to check if the token is OK. Auth server response with user details.

5.Application 2 now knows that the user is authorised and has some basic user details.

Note :
There are some existing implementations of this method, for example CAS (Central Authentication Service). Note that CAS is supported out of the box in Spring Security. . I have simplified things in my questions and there is a lot of potential for introducing security holes if you're new to this.

Comment: The block of text above lacks 2 things to qualify as a question: 1. the question mark; 2. the  description of what you have tried. The third thing that is lacking (this is more nice-to-have) is PARAGRAPHS!

Comment: ItWouldBeEasierToReadIfYouSplitItUpInPieces;-)

Comment: Please edit you question first, check this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting